# How can students view highlighted comments on their assignments in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-drive, google-classroom

Students have been submitting PDFs of their math homework in Google Classroom. I've been then clicking the "Add a comment" button to drag a highlight area over the section of the document I want to comment on. I might drag it over an equation and then write a little comment like "what happens if you move `x` to the other side?"

Unfortunately, it's just been made aware to me that students only see the yellow highlights over their PDFs when they view their assignment in Google Classroom :(. There's no obvious way for them to view all the notes I've been spending time writing!

Is there a way at all for students to view my notes? Is this a temporary bug in Google Classroom or an unimplemented feature? I was only able to find this [help page on providing feedback on assignments](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9093530?hl=en).

Here is an example of some feedback I provided. I dragged my mouse cursor to highlight "Therefore x would be a subset of A" and provided the comment shown.

[image: Example of feedback]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this isn't a Google Classroom bug as the comment feature that you are using is a feature of Google Drive, not a feature of Google Classroom.

I think that you could propose to the Google Classroom team a new feature to make the Google Drive comments easier to find for students. For this, use the submit feedback in app feature or go to the new official help forum https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/community

In the mean time, you could use the mention and assign comment features of Google Drive comments so the students could receive an email notification. For details see [Comment on Microsoft Office files, PDFs, images, and other files](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7650301?hl=en)